# Calendar script setting incorrect dates (day minus one)?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, date, calendar

I'm using Jason Moon's [Calendar Script](http://calendar.moonscript.com/dateinput.cfm) to allow users to set the date of an event. While this works fine for the year and month, I'm having issues getting it to set the correct day. It consistently sets the date of the event to one day previous to that the user selected; this occurs even if it means going back into the previous month (1 Aug becomes 31 July). I can't figure out why this is or what's doing it!

The client-side code is:

> `<script>`
>
> DateInput('publicationDate', true, "YYYY-MM-DD", `<`?php echo $results['article']->publicationDate ? "'".date( "Y-m-d", $results['article']->publicationDate )."'" : "" ?>);
>
> `</script>`

while the only bit of server-side code I can imagine causing this error is:

```
// Parse and store publication date
if ( isset( $params['publicationDate'] ) ) {
        $publicationDate = explode ( '-', $params['publicationDate'] );
        if ( count( $publicationDate ) == 3 ) {
            list ($y, $m, $d) = $publicationDate;
            $this->publicationDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Is it maybe related to the timezone I've set in my config file (America/Toronto)?

Comment: The script code doesn't look like valid javascript. What do you get on the client?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape the php tags - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the time in mktime to noon or something instead of 00:00:00 -- and you should explicitly declare a timezone anyway, as good practice. If it's consistently one day out, you can definitely do $d+1 in the mktime statement as suggested by @diEcho (but you said it was the date that was out, not the month, and I do believe that date is 1-indexed not 0 - but if it's consistently wrong, you can make it consistently fixed).

Comment: Thanks, I set mktime to noon and it worked fine! Do you have any idea why? Do mktime() and date() interpret the boundaries between days differently?

Comment: Yeah, exactly - I've seen it behave differently with 23:59:59 compared to 00:00:00 - I just figured noon would be totally unambiguous and impossible to misconstrue no matter what your environment thinks. :)

Answer (score 0):

it may be problem of `month` if it is then solution is below:

The value returned by `getMonth` is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

so to get the current month you always need to write `+1`

like this

```
var today = new Date(); 
var dd = today.getDate(); 
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0!
```

### [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

### [one more](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php)

Comment: Thanks, but the month is displaying just fine, and I'm getting and setting the month using PHP, not JavaScript.